# Image Upload Issue In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

The server cannot process the image. This can happen if the server is busy or does not have enough resources to complete the task. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2560 pixels.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpCaa.png)

Please check this image and help me to resolve this issue. Thanks!

I expecting is that i can find the solution easily.

Comment: If the image is good, i faced the similar issue due to corrupted wp_post table.